# Make background tabs to be always in hover state

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any extension or any way by which we can make all background tabs of firefox to be **always** in hover state.

Like this:
[image]

I'm new to add-ons development, I checked the tabs api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs, but did not find anything related to reading or manipulating hover event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspector shows that when tab is hovered it gets this style: chrome://browser/skin/browser.css line 2504

copy paste this to scratchpad it does the trick

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);

var css = '';
css += '.tab-background:not([selected=true]) {';
css += 'background-image: url(chrome://browser/skin/tabbrowser/tab-background-start.png),';
css += 'url(chrome://browser/skin/tabbrowser/tab-background-middle.png),';
css += 'url(chrome://browser/skin/tabbrowser/tab-background-end.png);';
css += 'background-position: left bottom, 30px bottom, right bottom;';
css += 'background-repeat: no-repeat;';
css += 'background-size: 30px 100%, calc(100% - (2 * 30px)) 100%, 30px 100%;';
css += '}';
var cssEncoded = encodeURIComponent(css);
var cssEncodedWithDataURL = 'data:text/css,' + cssEncoded;

var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(cssEncodedWithDataURL, null, null);

sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);

//sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET); //do this when you want to remove it
```